# opening one fancybox within another fancybox using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

Using the fancybox i can open the fancybox and i am using IFRAME. now i am trying to open another fancybox, all is going good.

but when i open the second fancybox, it creates a big black box under the same fancybox and opens another fancybox over it but it is not visible properly

parent fancybox

```
$(document).on('click','#table td a', function(e) {
            var call = e.currentTarget.toString();
            var create = call;
            $.fancybox({
                'width':840,
                'height':600,
                'type':'iframe',
                'autoScale':'false',
                openEffect: 'elastic',
                href:'child.php?mid='+encodeURIComponent(create),
                closeEffect: 'elastic'
            });
});
```

I am using the following code in my child fancybox code i am using as: the below code is in the `child.php` file

```
$(document).on('click','#table3 td font a', function(e) {
        var hrefcall = e.currentTarget.toString();
        $.fancybox({
            'width':840,
            'height':450,
            'type':'ajax',
            'modal': false,
            'autoScale':'true',
            openEffect: 'elastic',
            href:'next.php?iurl='+encodeURIComponent(hrefcall),
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            "overlayColor": "#ccc",  // here you set the background black
            "overlayOpacity": 1,  // here you set the transparency of background: 1 = opaque
            "hideOnOverlayClick": true,  // if true, closes fancybox when clicking OUTSIDE the box
            "hideOnContentClick": true
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

now this works but as i said, it exapnds a big grey box at the bottom and opens the new fancybox which is not properly visible.

i want the parent fancybox to be greyed when this is opened.

I am using fancybox version 2.0.3

Comment: if you are opening an iframe, any link inside the iframe will open a new page inside the same fancybox. You don't need to load fancybox nor bind fancybox to your links inside the iframed page

Comment: so how to fix this issue, i am getting lost here

Comment: Nothing to fix, just don't use fancybox in your child.php page

Comment: but the project demands that another fancybox should be used, i am now lost, u are the experienced guy i seen everywhere answering fancybox questions, please guide

Comment: You cannot have two fancybox open at the same time. Even if you manage to launch a second fancybox from the first, the first will be closed.